# Mystery plastic part

Tags: lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo T60 at work and in my bag I got an Mystery item that came with it. It seems to me that it belong to the Laptop too, or may be not, but can't figure out where it goes. Wonder if anyone knows what is the user of this item. It just bother me so much that I can't find a use for that :D

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Perhaps it's some kind of webcam stand?

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: Making this and convincing somebody to ship it would be the best prank ever!

Comment: #3, its a mini barbers chair.

Comment: I've never seen anything like it in any thinkpad i've seen

Comment: Most likely this is something for docking purposes, have you checked the manual?

Comment: As for why this was closed: [Let’s Play The Guessing Game « Blog – Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/)